# How to filter and fetch GitHub repositories by topics

Tags: api, github, open-source, github-api

I wanted to fetch GitHub repositories that come under a certain topic from the GitHub API.

For eg. I fetch all repos using `https://api.github.com/repositories`.
And I fetch a topic by using `https://api.github.com/search/topics?q=<TOPIC_NAME>`.

But I want to fetch repositories that come under a topic. Let's say for JavaScript: https://github.com/topics/javascript

All the repos that are on this webpage is what I want to fetch using GitHub API. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this API URL:

```js
const url = `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:${TOPIC}`
```

curl request for the same if you are using any API client:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic%3Ajavascript' \
  --header 'accept: application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json'
```