# How to filter GitHub repositories of an user by topics

Tags: github, github-api

I already see similar topics, but no one solve my problem.

> [How to filter and fetch GitHub repositories by topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388594/how-to-filter-and-fetch-github-repositories-by-topics?rq=1)

> [Github API: Getting topics of a Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259946/github-api-getting-topics-of-a-github-repository)

The problem is:
When I request for `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:${TOPIC}`
they give me the repositories form the whole world, so well, I just want to get from a unique user or organization.

I know about `https://api.github.com/users/{user}`

but it doesn't seem to filter by topics, so I would have to search through a hundred repositories to match the topic I need.

Is there any API feature that helps me?

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to get from a unique user or organization.

You need to add to the `q` parameter [what you are looking for](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search#constructing-a-search-query):

By user:

```
q=user:Foo topic:Bar
```

By org:

```
q=org:Acme topic:Bar
```

(remember to URL encode the `q` parameter)

[Here](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-for-repositories#search-within-a-users-or-organizations-repositories) you can find all the GH supported parameters